# SQL: Drop Column Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, rename, alter

I want to drop a column from my table. I have tried executing the following syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE user
DROP COLUMN departmentid;
```

On execution, it hits me with an error stating that the statement could not be prepared. Can anyone tell me why it's doing this? I get the same error when I try renaming a column.

Comment: which Database provider? MYSQL, Oracle, Sql Server?

Comment: I am using MySQL - if it helps, I am on the SQL query builder provided by w3schools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you are using *MySQL*, Try using

   `DROP departmentid;`
2. Use BackTicks `'column name'` in the query.
3. It might not be possible to DELETE, INSERT or ALTER a table in online query builders. because once you drop tables, others cannot play around with same table. So I dont thing you have privileges to do so. If you are learning install `xamp` which has installed apache server and `MySQL`.

Hope this info helps!

Comment: Already tried that, gives me the same "cant prepare statement" error.

Comment: I am using the query builder provided by w3schools, it might be possible that they don't grant privileges to do so. However, some of the example statements they provide allow you to drop, alter and insert. I create a new table, try renaming or dropping a column, doesn't work!!

Comment: I have got wamp installed on my personal laptop, I am currently on a work machine, just doing some small sql revision, thought I go over what I already know, I think you're right about the privileges. I've already tried it with back ticks, that's the first thing I tried lol. Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: Glad that Helped :) . If that answer was helpful you can tick it right, or upvote. Just telling :).

Comment: Thank you, I have to earn a reputation of 15 before I can upvote.. but sure!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by executing below query:
I need to remove a column and all the entries from that column to free my DB size
my initial table structure is as shown below:

***CREATE TABLE words(_id,word,synonyms,favorite,history,updDate)***

And I wanted the table in below form

***CREATE TABLE words(_id,word,favorite,history,updDate)***

So I executed below query and it removed "synonyms" column

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1_backup(_id,word,favorite,history,updDate);
INSERT INTO t1_backup SELECT _id,word,favorite,history,updDate FROM words;
DROP TABLE words;
CREATE TABLE words(_id,word,favorite,history,updDate);
INSERT INTO words SELECT _id,word,favorite,history,updDate FROM t1_backup;
DROP TABLE t1_backup
COMMIT;
```